# How to transfer ID of image from carousel_pro flutter

Tags: flutter

How to transfer ID if user onTap image to other page from carousel_pro.
I get Image to carousel_pro from database mysql. I try to make user can click image and move to other page with id of image.
full my code:

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: Demo()));

class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<Demo> {
String SelectIdCategory;
bool lodaing=true;
  List data;
  Future GetAllCategory()async{
    var response=await http.get("https://****************.php"
        , headers: {"Accept": "application/json"}
    );
    var jsoBody = response.body;
    var jsoData =json.decode(jsoBody);
    setState(() {
      data= jsoData;
      lodaing=false;
    });
      print('show all data $jsoData');
  }
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    GetAllCategory();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Scaffold(
      body:lodaing?   CircularProgressIndicator() :

      GestureDetector(

        child: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 150.0,
          width: 300.0,

          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {


            },

            child: Carousel(
            //    onImageTap:(index) { print(index.toString()); } ,
              boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
              autoplay: true,
              dotSize: 4.0,
              dotSpacing: 15.0,
              dotColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
              indicatorBgPadding: 5.0,
              dotBgColor: Colors.purple.withOpacity(0.5),
              borderRadius: true,
              //   onImageChange: (prev, next) {_selectedIndex = next;}, initialIndex: selectedItem,
              images:

              data  .map(
                    (list) {

                  return Image.network(list['image']);


                },
              ).toList(),


            ),



          ),
        ),
      ),
      )




    );
  }
}
class ImageScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String id;
  ImageScreen(this.id);

  @override
  _MyImageScreen createState() => _MyImageScreen(id);
}

class _MyImageScreen extends State<ImageScreen> {
  final String id;
  _MyImageScreen(this.id);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('ImageScreen'),
        ),
        body: Center());
  }
}
```

Here is the print result:

```
I/flutter (24335): show all data [{id: 1, name: one, image: https://*****************/image},
 {id: 3, name: one, image: https://*****************/image}]
```

As you can see from print data I have two image and each image has a id different. That what I want to send to other page.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should define a "skeleton" of your app.
Do you prefer to use global variables to store values at runtime? Do you want to send parameters through pages without let them in app ram?

If you want to send data thor pages your class for the new page should accept parameters.. so you can pass the id.

or you can set a global variable with the currentImageId then in the new page you can access that variable

To accept parameters in the new page you have to declare final variables then in the signature of the class you request them.. something like this

```
class DetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
    final int yourId;
    DetailPage(this.yourId);
}
```

Comment: Hello brother / Yes, I would like to send the ID to the next page, but I do not know how to do that